# cannot change class of <img> tag

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to find all  tags on the page and change their class from 'multiimage' to 'mySpace' but i cannot see any changes on the page and when I log this elemets into console I can see ther className set as 'multiimage'.

My code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // to store all <img> elements
    var arrayOfMultiImages = new Array();
    var multiImageNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("multiimage").length;
    // store <img> tag in array
    for(var i = 0; i < multiImageNumber; i++){
        arrayOfMultiImages.push(document.getElementsByClassName("multiimage")[i]);
    }
    // change className of <img> elements
    for(var x = 0; x < multiImageNumber.length; x++){
        arrayOfMultiImages[x].className = "mySpace";
    }
    // cannot see any changes
    console.log(arrayOfMultiImages);
};
```

Don't you have any idea what is wrong there?

Comment: `multiImageNumber.length`? `multiImageNumber` is a number already.

Comment: also.....`getElementsByClassName()` already gives you an array-like structure of the elements, why are you putting them into an actual array, just loop over the original collection

Comment: I'm removing this images later but I need to store them somewhere because they can be used again. Could I do it easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multiImageNumber` variable is **already a number**, following line of code doesn't have any kind of sense:
`for(var x = 0; x < multiImageNumber.length; x++){`

**Another case** - `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like object, containing all elements with specified class. There's **no need** to iterate over it and push every single element into a new array.

If you want to change an array-like object into an array, use `Array#from`.
It's a build-in function, coming from **ES6**.

```
var arrayOfMultiImages = document.getElementsByClassName('multiimage');
var array = Array.from(arrayOfMultiImages);
```

**Once** you have changed your array-like object into an array, you can use e.g. `Array#forEach` function to simply and quickly iterate over it's elements.

```
array.forEach(elem => elem.className = "mySpace")
```

### Simple example:

```js
let elems = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.className = 'mySpace');
```

```css
.box {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.mySpace {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Array from is a build in function? I see edits, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this code by looping through the collection returned by `getElementsByClassName()`, then change the `className` from that loop.

```js
var multiImageNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("multiimage");
for (var x = 0; x < multiImageNumber.length; x++) {
  multiImageNumber[x].className = "mySpace";
}
```

```css
.mySpace {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="foo">
<img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="multiimage">
<img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="bar">
```